# jQuery add class based on page URL with separate classes

Tags: jquery, html, css

I wanted to find a way to extract from the url the classes to be added to the body. I made some attempts but I only managed to get the last piece of the url.
Do you know how I could do?

this is what I tried to do with jquery

```
var dir= window.location.pathname.split('?')[0].split('/').filter(function (i) { return i !== ""}).slice(-1)[0]
jQuery("body").addClass(dir);
```

this is what i have:

```
 http://www.test.com/news/hello/
<body class="hello"></body>

http://www.test.com/news/
<body class="news"></body>
```

this is what I would like to have

```
 http://www.test.com/news/hello/
    <body class="hello news"></body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `slice` method return an array so all you need to do is removing the `[0]` so that you can have all your classes.

You should also put 2 as the paramater of `slice` so that it can take all your classes after your base url.

```js
var url = " http://www.test.com/news/hello/"
var dir = url
        .split('?')[0]
        .split('/')
        .filter(function (i) { return i !== ""})
        .slice(2);
        
$("div p").addClass(dir);
```

```css
.news {
  color: red;
}

.hello {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <p>Hello world</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are explicitly taking the last element of the array with `.slice(-1)[0]`, try something, you can just use the result of the filter method without the `slice` call.